# Convert Netlify site to an PDF file

Tags: netlify

I'd tried several sites to convert a netlify site to an pdf, but nothing seems to work for me.

Is there any possible way to convert a Netlify site to an Pdf file ?

Answer (score -1):

Just solved the problem. I went through these steps:

**How To Save a Webpage as a PDF in Chrome**

Open the page you’d like to keep.

On the top left-hand corner, click File > Print.

Alternatively, press Ctrl + P (Windows) or Cmd + P (Mac)

Under the ‘Destination’ section, click Change... > Save as PDF

Click the ‘Save’ button, pick the name and location for your PDF.